# C# Auto-Implemented Properties Assistance

Tags: c#, properties

In C# I'm confused about properties.  Specifically when you set get and set as just `{ get; set;}`.  What does it mean when you do that?  For example I have class property:

```
public Dictionary<string, string> clientDict { get; set; }
```

I've seen properties where they actually define get and set.  I also understand that removing set makes it read only.  But what happens in this case?  Does it just use the default accessors of a normal dict?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx

Comment: The CLR will create behind the seen a local variable for you  so this is the same as : `private Dictionary<string, string> _clientDict;
        public Dictionary<string, string> ClientDict
        {
            get
            {

                return _clientDict;
            }
            set
            {
                _clientDict = value;
            }
        }`

Comment: @BelahceneBenzaraTahar *The CLR will create behind the seen* ... the compiler ...

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair, +1 for the correction :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. this is called "Automatic Properties". (when you just write the set and the get method without any code inside them)
2. the target of the Automatic Properties is the simplifying the coding process, and make it faster.
3. when you write a property like the previous one.

   public Dictionary clientDict { get; set; }

the compiler translates it to the following

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _clientDic;

public Dictionary<string, string> clientDic
{ 
     get { return _clientDic; }
     set { _clientDic = value; }
}
```

and when you write a property like the following one

```
public int X {get;}
```

the compiler translates it to the following

```
private int _x;

public int X{
    get { return _x; }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You may be confusing the accessors to a *class member* with the accessors to a *collection*. As a commenter noted, the MSDN page on [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) explains that this:

```cs
public Dictionary<string, string> clientDict { get; set; }
```

Is equivalent to this:

```cs
private Dictionary<string, string> _clientDict;

public Dictionary<string, string> clientDict
{
    get { return _clientDict; }
    set(Dictionary<string, string> value)
    {
        _clientDict = value;
    }
}
```

Those accessors just return a reference to the collection. They aren't passing anything through (as implied by your question "Does it just use the default accessors of a normal dict?"), and they are unrelated to the `Dictionary<T>` class's `[]` and `.Add()` methods.

When you access the Dictionary through the property:

```cs
var foo = clientDict["SomeKey"];
```

That will first return the result of the `clientDict`* property's access, namely, a reference to `_clientDict`, and will then index into that dictionary, returning the resulting value (assuming the key exists) and assigning it to `foo`.

Please comment or edit the question if something further is confusing you about auto-properties.

** By the way, it's taking everything I've got not to write `ClientDict` as the name of the property, since the C# convention is to capitalize property names just like method names :)*

Answer (score 2):

```
public Dictionary<string, string> clientDict { get; set; }
```

Is equivalent to defining `get` and `set` manually. The compiler handles all of it for you behind the scenes. So your above would become:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _clientDict;
public Dictionary<string, string> clientDict;
{
   get { return _clientDict; }
   set { _clientDict = value; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify it. What would it mean if it were `int` instead of `Dictionary`?

```
public int ClientInt {get;set;}
```

There are no accessors for `int`, so you wouldn't find yourself asking that question.

Comment: Yes but what I'm asking is by setting them as get; set; rather than get { implementation here } set { implementation here} mean?  Does it just use           the base Dictionary classes get/set methods

Comment: Ask yourself: what does it do for `int`

Answer (score 0):

> In C# I'm confused about properties. Specifically when you set get and
>   set as just { get; set;}. **What does it mean when you do that?**

It means you're defining an `Automatic Property`, and behind the scenes, the compilers creates a private, anonymous `backing field` that can only be accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

---

So, your next question might be...

> What's a `backing field`?

A `backing field` is a `field` which a `property` references to store and retrieve values from.

You've seen what an `automatic property` looks like, here's what a `property` with a `backing field` looks like...

```
private string name; // Backing field

public string Name   // Property 
{
    get { return this.name; }
    set { this.name = value }
}
```

---

> I've seen properties where they actually define get and set. I also
>   understand that removing set makes it read only.

Yes it makes the `Property` read-only, but be careful, as `C#` also contains a `keyword` called `readonly` which is set on `Fields`. E.g. `private readonly string name;`..

Just as properties can be `read only`, they can also be `write only`, if you remove the `Get` accessor, and only leave the `Set` accessor, clients will only be able to write to it.

> But what happens in this case? Does it just use the default accessors of a normal dict?

The dictionary example you've given above will have a backing field... Clients will be able to write to it and read from it.

We could change things up if we wanted however...

Imagine that we're providing the scores of a live football game, giving `write` access to clients would be a nightmare... so we could restrict that and only expose a `get` accessor, whilst keeping the `set` accessor private.

```
public int TeamFoo { get; private set; }
public int TeamBar { get; private set; }
```

Or, we could do it with an explicitly defined backing field...

```
private int teamFoo;
public int TeamFoo { get { return teamFoo; } }
```